# Python dataframes: how can I return the number of occurrences in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am working with a large csv file that has information that looks something like

```
id      year   decade  code  type
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical
427     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm
337     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm
337     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm
```

I would like to sort by the number of unique occurrences in the 'id' column. My desired result would look something like

```
id      year   decade  code  type          count
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical        5
427     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   1
337     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   2
```

However I was trying to settle for something like

```
id      year   decade  code  type           count
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical        5
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical        5
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical        5
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical        5
3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical        5
427     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   1
337     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   1
337     1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   2
```

I attempted to do this by trying

```
df['count']=df.groupby('id').transform('count')
```

But I keep getting an error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 18, placement implies 1
```

Is there a better way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: `df["count"] =  df.groupby("id")["type"].transform("count")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

- `.size()` will get you counts, but create a multi-level index
- `.reset_index()` will get rid of the multi-level index with the counts contained in a column named 0
- `.rename(columns = {0:'count'})` will rename this column to count

You can use transform, but make sure you pass a series the same length as your dataframe. You can do this by adding `['year']` to your groupby, but any of your columns will do:

```
df['counts'] = df.groupby('id')['year'].transform('count')
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the explanation as well.

Comment: Can you also explain exactly where your solution specifies to group by 'id'? The solutions works perfectly for the simple example that I gave. However, when applying it to the actual dataframe that I am working with, every single row in the 'count' column returns 1. I'm thinking that it should also work for my actual data set. The only difference is that there are more rows and columns, but the grouping and everything should remain the same.

Comment: Grouping by `['id', 'year', 'decade', 'code', 'type']` in the case of the stack overflow question example, produces repeat records, which is reason the groupby produces counts greater than one.

In other words, if the combination of columns included in the groupby parentheses produce unique records, the `size()` or `.transform('count')` will be one.

Comment: Is it possible for me to only group by `id`? With your explanation, I think that the reason why it is not working on my actual dataframe is because there is some differences between the other columns that I am not as concerned with. Maybe a solution would be to delete the columns that I deem unnecessary as I am only concerned about half of the 19 columns.

Comment: I deleted all of the irrelevant columns and got the result that I wanted, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For the first desired solution:

```
data = data.groupby(['id',  'year', 'decade',   'code', 'type']).id.count()
data
id    year  decade  code  type         
337   1972  1970    DR    Coastal Storm    2
427   1972  1970    DR    Coastal Storm    1
3366  2014  2010    EM    Chemical         5
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

For the second:

```
data['count'] = data.groupby(['id', 'year', 'decade',   'code', 'type']).id.transform('count')
data
id  year    decade  code    type    count
0   3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical    5
1   3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical    5
2   3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical    5
3   3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical    5
4   3366    2014    2010    EM  Chemical    5
5   427 1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   1
6   337 1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   2
7   337 1972    1970    DR  Coastal Storm   2
```

Data:

```
id;year;decade;code;type
3366;2014;2010;EM;Chemical
3366;2014;2010;EM;Chemical
3366;2014;2010;EM;Chemical
3366;2014;2010;EM;Chemical
3366;2014;2010;EM;Chemical
427;1972;1970;DR;Coastal Storm
337;1972;1970;DR;Coastal Storm
337;1972;1970;DR;Coastal Storm

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';')
```

Comment: Ok, I have seen it. You just need to reassign it back to itself. Please see my edit

Comment: Yes, it solves one part. I am now having the same issue with both solutions that were provided here. Both work perfectly for the example that I gave. However, when applying it to my actual dataset, it doesn't seem to work as well. In my original dataframe, I am starting with about 51,000 rows. Once I run the groupby statement, it reduces to about 39,000. But the 'count' column is always returning 1. I can also see that there are repeats within the 'id' column. I'm just trying to figure out what I am missing.